# Is there performance difference between NumericVector and vector<double>?

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpp11

Suppose one uses `NumericVector` and the other uses `vector<double>` in their Rcpp code. Is there notable difference between the two usages, especially in performance?

Comment: well, gosh, why don't you just try it out?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I did some benchmark tests in simple situations, but there's no notable difference at all. That's why I want to know about it in more general sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally, yes.

All of the Rcpp(11) types are "thin proxy objects" (which we talk about in several places, talks, slide decks, my book, ...) around the underlying `SEXP` objects. That means no copies are made when you go from R to C++, and when you go back from C++ to R.

Using standard C++ types like `std::vector<T>`, however, generally requires a copy.

So you should easily see a difference on some trivial test script as `N` increases enough.

Personally speaking, I generally like the "clean" use of C++ / STL types for code that "feels more C++-ish" but remain aware of the performance penalty.  Often it does not really matter as the C++ solution is faster than what you replace in a pure R solution.

But your question is if one dominates the other, and the other is a clear yes.

Comment: This assumes that the vector was passed to the C++ program. What about a program that only uses such vectors internally or one which does pass them but is so time consuming that the one-time passing is negligible relative to the rest of the computation?  Which would be faster then?